# Rich Text Editor for iOS

Tags: ios, editor, richtextbox

My users have asked if I can add a Rich Text type editor to my app. The field that they want this added to is a UITextView.
Obviously, they also will want to see the text displayed as they've entered it.
Any suggestions for how to implement this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe this should be of help: https://github.com/nnhubbard/ZSSRichTextEditor

Comment: What did you decide? Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 approaches - a UiTexView can handle most Rich Text Editor stuff not including lists. 
The 2nd way is a WebView and some html / JavaScript. 
A WebView might be the best approach but be careful - some of the WebView based solutions out there were rejected from the AppStore since they use private methods of the WebView - that is not allowed by Apple.